# Como definir largura da coluna do Grid View?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Gostaria de saber como definir a largura das colunas do `DataGridView` manualmente.

A minha primeira coluna tem que ter um valor fixo e as demais colunas devem "preencher" o grid, de forma que elas fiquem do mesmo tamanho.

Comment: WinForms ou WebForms?

Comment: usando o WinForms...

Comment: Você quer fixar o tamanho da primeira coluna e fazer com as outras tenham o tamanho automático, mas todas elas com o mesmo tamanho (com exceção da primeira, claro). Certo?

Comment: isso mesmo @jbueno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Via design

Primeiro clique na setinha no canto superior direito do `DataGridView` e clique em **Edit Columns**. Isso abrirá um form com todas as colunas do seu Grid, então você seleciona na coluna que quer deixar o tamanho fixo (`TESTE1` nesse caso) e define o valor da propriedade `Width` do lado direito da tela.

Depois disso você só precisa alterar a propriedade `AutoSizeMode` de todas as outras colunas para `Fill`.

[image: DataGridView]

## Via código

Você disse que cria as colunas dinamicamente, o que lhe impossibilita de fazer o que eu disse acima. A solução seria iterar as colunas do `DataGridView` e definir os tamanhos depois de que o grid estiver populado.

```
foreach(DataGridViewColumn column in dgNotas.Columns)
{
    if (column.DataPropertyName == "primeiraColuna")
        column.Width = 100; //tamanho fixo da primeira coluna

    column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
}
```

Comment: Deu certinho obrigada!